# Unable to load patterns in AIML via Python

Tags: python, aiml

I've installed AIML via pip and wrote files *startup.py*, *std-startup.xml*, *basic.aiml* and *bot_brain.brn* in **core** folder. When I try to run *startup.py*, I get this warning:

```
Loading std-startup.xml... done (0.06 seconds)
WARNING: No match found for input: load aiml b

Kernel bootstrap completed in 0.10 seconds
Saving brain to core/bot_brain.brn... done (0.00 seconds)
```

This is the content of *std-startup.xml*:

```
<aiml version="1.0.1" encoding="UTF-8">
    <!-- std-startup.xml -->

    <category>
        <pattern>load aiml b</pattern>
        <template>
            <learn>basic.aiml</learn>
        </template>
    </category>

</aiml>
```

This is Python script:

```
import aiml
import os

kernel = aiml.Kernel()

if os.path.isfile("core/bot_brain.brn"):
    kernel.bootstrap(brainFile = "core/bot_brain.brn")
else:
    kernel.bootstrap(learnFiles = "std-startup.xml", commands = "load aiml b")
    kernel.saveBrain("core/bot_brain.brn")

while True:
    msg = raw_input(">")
    if msg == "exit":
        exit(0)
    elif msg == "save":
        kernel.saveBrain("core/bot_brain.brn")
    else:
        bot_response = kernel.respond(msg)
        print("bot: " + bot_response)
```

For every input I get error `No match found for input`. What I'm doing wrong? Everything is in the same directory, except the *bot_brain.brn*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved; I had to enter it with uppercase letters:

```
<category>
    <pattern>LOAD AIML B</pattern>
    <template>
        <learn>basic.aiml</learn>
    </template>
</category>
```